# Altair doesn't plot when the source is a Pandas DatafFame

Tags: python, dataframe, charts, data-science, altair

I can't plot a simple Pandas DataFrame to an Area Chart using Altair. The point is that the chart works if I import the very same DataFrame using Vega ("source = data.iowa_electricity()"), for example.

```
source = {
    'year': ['2001-01-01', '2002-01-01'],
    'source': ['Fossil Fuels', 'Nuclear Energy'],
    'net_generation': [35361, 35991]
}
source = pd.DataFrame(source) ### this DF doesn't work

chart = alt.Chart(source).mark_area(opacity=0.3).encode(
    x="year",
    y=alt.Y("net_generation:Q", stack=None),
    color=f"source:N"
)
```

If I change the above "source" to "source = data.iowa_electricity()" (**which contains the very same data inside**), the chart works pretty fine.

What am I missing here?

PS: the same occurs using only string as labels (without dates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is not identical: the dictionary only has one entry per color, while the iowa electricity dataset has many entries per color.

As I mentioned in the answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62905557/2937831), an area chart with a single point per color will show nothing, because the area under a single point has zero width and thus is invisible.

You can confirm this by adding more than one point to each group:

```
source = {
    'year': ['2001-01-01', '2001-01-02', '2001-01-01', '2001-01-02'],
    'source': ['Fossil Fuels', 'Fossil Fuels', 'Nuclear Energy', 'Nuclear Energy'],
    'net_generation': [100, 500, 200, 400]
}
source = pd.DataFrame(source)

chart = alt.Chart(source).mark_area(opacity=0.3).encode(
    x="year:T",
    y=alt.Y("net_generation:Q", stack=None),
    color="source:N"
)
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to use the difference of all "net_generation" values of my DF as width for the data points?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Maybe ask another question with more detail?